# The sum of all the numbers in a set is 30...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of elements in the set if the average of these numbers is seven less than the number of elements in the set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\sum a_i=30$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum a_i= N-7$. Can you figure out how to solve these two equations? Try substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of elements in the set be $x$.

Then we have $$\frac{30}{x}=x-7$$
Implying, $$30 = x^2 - 7x$$
$$x^2-7x-30=0$$
$$(x-10)(x+3)=0$$
$$x=10,-3$$

We cannot have a negative number of elements in the set so there are 10 elements.